# Using virtual functions to make a guessing game in C++

Tags: c++

I am doing one of my final homework for my c++ class and I'm confused.

Instructions:

*Listed below is code to play a guessing game in which two players attempt to guess a number. Your task is to extend the program with objects that represent either a human player or a computer player.*

*The play function takes as input two Player objects. Define the Player class with a virtual function named getGuess(). The implementation of Player::getGuess() can simply return 0. Next, define a class named HumanPlayer derived from Player. The implementation of HumanPlayer::getGuess() should prompt the user to enter a number and return the value entered from the keyboard. Next, define a class named ComputerPlayer derived from Player. The implementation of ComputerPlayer::getGuess() should randomly select a number from 0 to 100. Finally, construct a main function that invokes play(Player &player1, Player &player2) with two instances of a HumanPlayer (human vs. human), an instance of a HumanPlayer and ComputerPlayer (human vs. computer), and two instances of ComputerPlayer (computer vs. computer).*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

class Player {
   public:
      virtual int getGuess();
      int guess;
};

class ComputerPlayer : public Player {
   public:
      ComputerPlayer() : Player(){}
      int getGuess() {
         return rand() % 100 + 1;
      }
};

class HumanPlayer : public Player {
   public:
      HumanPlayer() : Player() {}
      int getGuess() {
         cout << "Please enter your guess: ";
         cin >> guess;
         return guess;
      }
};


bool checkForWin(int guess, int answer)
{
  if (answer == guess)
  {
     cout << "You're right! You win!" << endl;
     return true;
  }
  else if (answer < guess)
     cout << "Your guess is too high." << endl;
  else
     cout << "Your guess is too low." << endl;
  return false;
}

void play(Player &player1, Player &player2)
{
  int answer = 0, guess = 0;
  answer = rand() % 100;
  bool win = false;

  while (!win)
  {
   cout << "Player 1's turn to guess." << endl;
   guess = player1.getGuess();
   win = checkForWin(guess, answer);
   if (win) return;

   cout << "Player 2's turn to guess." << endl;
   guess = player2.getGuess();
   win = checkForWin(guess, answer);
  }
}

int main()
{
    srand(1);
    HumanPlayer humanPlayer1, humanPlayer2;
    ComputerPlayer computerPlayer1, computerPlayer2;

    cout << "Human vs Human\n";
    cout << "Press a key to continue...";
    char c;
    cin >> c;
    play(humanPlayer1, humanPlayer2);

    cout << "Human vs Computer\n";
    cout << "Press a key to continue...";
    cin >> c;
    play(humanPlayer1, computerPlayer1);

    cout << "Computer vs Computer\n";
    cout << "Press a key to continue...";
    cin >> c;
    play(computerPlayer1, computerPlayer2);

    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting the following compiling error:

```
/tmp/cctJstdH.o: In function `Player::Player()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN6PlayerC2Ev[_ZN6PlayerC5Ev]+0x9): undefined reference to `vtable for Player'
/tmp/cctJstdH.o:(.rodata._ZTI11HumanPlayer[_ZTI11HumanPlayer]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Player'
/tmp/cctJstdH.o:(.rodata._ZTI14ComputerPlayer[_ZTI14ComputerPlayer]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Player'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no implementation of `Player::getGuess()` virtual method. Add implementation or declare the class as pure virtual by adding `= 0`:

```
class Player
{
    // ...
    virtual int getGuess() = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the instructions super carefully.

**"The implementation of Player::getGuess() can simply return 0."**

Your `class Player` doesn't implement `Player::getGuess()` at all.

This should fix it:

```
class Player {
   public:
      virtual int getGuess() { return 0; } // implement this function
      int guess;
};
```